# Saving state after logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some questions which I will ask a user when they login for a web app. Questions will be asked one at a time. If a user logouts without completing the set of questions, the state will be saved and next time the user logins, the questions will start from the previous state where user logged out.

What state saving mechanism/gem I should use in `Rails 4.2` to efficiently handle this scenario?

Comment: If you mean to do it on client-side then using localstorage is the easy way to do that.

Comment: I mean to do it on server side in Rails. Will aasm state machine be a good idea?

Comment: Client side local storage will fail if a user logs in from some other browser..thus server side implemention will be better..I was thinking of wicked gem or aasm